# Adding filter to image in swing

Tags: java, image, swing

I need to set filter to the image..
I make this :

```
        int type = BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB;
        double panelHeight = frame.getHeight();
        double panelWidth = frame.getWidth();
        BufferedImage image = null;
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File(frame.getURL()));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        int height = image.getHeight();
        int width = image.getWidth();
        for(int h=1; h < height-1; h++) {
            for(int w=1; w < width-1;w++) {
                float color = ((1f/9f*image.getRGB(w-1, h-1))+(1f/9f* image.getRGB(w, h-1))+(1f/9f* image.getRGB(w+1, h-1))+
                        (1f/9f* image.getRGB(w-1, h))+(1f/9f* image.getRGB(w, h))+(1f/9f* image.getRGB(w+1, h))+
                        (1f/9f* image.getRGB(w-1, h+1))-(1f/9f* image.getRGB(w, h+1))-(1f/9f* image.getRGB(w+1, h+1)));
                image.setRGB(w, h,(int)color);   
            }
        }
        //save im into a file 
        frame.setFilteredImage(Resizer.resize(image, panelHeight, panelWidth));
```

frame has url of my image. I get it using `frame.getURL()`

And in result I want to see my image with blur filter but instead it gives me 
[image]

So may be someone know where I make a mistake???

Or may be you know another good way to set filter using such matrix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use blurFilter

```
public class Java2DExample extends JFrame {
  private JMenu filterMenu = new JMenu("Image Filters");

  private ImagePanel imagePanel;

  private MyFilter invertFilter = new InvertFilter();

  private MyFilter sharpenFilter = new SharpenFilter();

  private MyFilter blurFilter = new BlurFilter();

  private MyFilter colorFilter = new ColorFilter();

  public Java2DExample() {
    super("Java 2D Image Processing Demo");
    imagePanel = new ImagePanel(Java2DExample.class.getResource("yourImage.png"));

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    filterMenu.setMnemonic('I');

    JMenuItem originalMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Display Original");
    originalMenuItem.setMnemonic('O');

    originalMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent action) {
        imagePanel.displayOriginalImage();
      }

    });

    JMenuItem invertMenuItem = createMenuItem("Invert", 'I', invertFilter);
    JMenuItem sharpenMenuItem = createMenuItem("Sharpen", 'S', sharpenFilter);
    JMenuItem blurMenuItem = createMenuItem("Blur", 'B', blurFilter);
    JMenuItem changeColorsMenuItem = createMenuItem("Change Colors", 'C', colorFilter);

    filterMenu.add(originalMenuItem);
    filterMenu.add(invertMenuItem);
    filterMenu.add(sharpenMenuItem);
    filterMenu.add(blurMenuItem);
    filterMenu.add(changeColorsMenuItem);

    menuBar.add(filterMenu);

    getContentPane().add(imagePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

  }

  public JMenuItem createMenuItem(String menuItemName, char mnemonic, final MyFilter filter) {
    JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem(menuItemName);
    menuItem.setMnemonic(mnemonic);
    menuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent action) {
        imagePanel.applyFilter(filter);
      }

    });
    return menuItem;
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Java2DExample application = new Java2DExample();
    application.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    application.pack();
    application.setVisible(true);
  }
}

interface MyFilter {
  public abstract BufferedImage processImage(BufferedImage image);
}

class BlurFilter implements MyFilter {
  public BufferedImage processImage(BufferedImage image) {
    float[] blurMatrix = { 1.0f / 9.0f, 1.0f / 9.0f, 1.0f / 9.0f, 1.0f / 9.0f, 1.0f / 9.0f,
        1.0f / 9.0f, 1.0f / 9.0f, 1.0f / 9.0f, 1.0f / 9.0f };
    BufferedImageOp blurFilter = new ConvolveOp(new Kernel(3, 3, blurMatrix),
        ConvolveOp.EDGE_NO_OP, null);
    return blurFilter.filter(image, null);
  }
}

class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

  private BufferedImage displayImage;

  private BufferedImage originalImage;

  private Image image;

  public ImagePanel(URL imageURL) {
    image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(imageURL);
    MediaTracker mediaTracker = new MediaTracker(this);
    mediaTracker.addImage(image, 0);

    try {
      mediaTracker.waitForAll();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    originalImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null),
        BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    displayImage = originalImage;
    Graphics2D graphics = displayImage.createGraphics();
    graphics.drawImage(image, null, null);

  }

  public void applyFilter(MyFilter filter) {
    displayImage = filter.processImage(displayImage);
    repaint();
  }

  public void displayOriginalImage() {
    displayImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null),
        BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    Graphics2D graphics = displayImage.createGraphics();
    graphics.drawImage(originalImage, null, null);
    repaint();
  }
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) g;
    graphics.drawImage(displayImage, 0, 0, null);
  }
  public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(displayImage.getWidth(), displayImage.getHeight());
  }
  public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
    return getPreferredSize();
  }
}

class SharpenFilter implements MyFilter {
  public BufferedImage processImage(BufferedImage image) {
    float[] sharpenMatrix = { 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 5.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f };
    BufferedImageOp sharpenFilter = new ConvolveOp(new Kernel(3, 3, sharpenMatrix),
        ConvolveOp.EDGE_NO_OP, null);
    return sharpenFilter.filter(image, null);
  }
}

class InvertFilter implements MyFilter {
  public BufferedImage processImage(BufferedImage image) {
    byte[] invertArray = new byte[256];

    for (int counter = 0; counter < 256; counter++)
      invertArray[counter] = (byte) (255 - counter);

    BufferedImageOp invertFilter = new LookupOp(new ByteLookupTable(0, invertArray), null);
    return invertFilter.filter(image, null);

  }
}

class ColorFilter implements MyFilter {
  public BufferedImage processImage(BufferedImage image) {
    float[][] colorMatrix = { { 1f, 0f, 0f }, { 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.5f }, { 0.2f, 0.4f, 0.6f } };
    BandCombineOp changeColors = new BandCombineOp(colorMatrix, null);
    Raster sourceRaster = image.getRaster();
    WritableRaster displayRaster = sourceRaster.createCompatibleWritableRaster();
    changeColors.filter(sourceRaster, displayRaster);
    return new BufferedImage(image.getColorModel(), displayRaster, true, null);

  }
}
```

ref: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/ImageFilter.htm

Comment: Yes I trying this(this method works with JDK7) but when I use JDK6 it gives me error    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.image.ImagingOpException: Unable to convolve src image